# how to get a form side by side to a div

Tags: css, html

I'm building a menu that scrolls down with the page for example Facebook's menu but i'm having trouble, the form seems to go under the div and i tried making it float left and it still doesn't work, i want to make it so their all lined up in a line.. what am i doing wrong?

here is my code

```
<div id="topnav"> 


<div id="nav">
<a href="../index"><img src="/img/putlockermedia_logo.png" /></a>

<a href="../Shows"><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Shows" /></a>

<a href="../movies"><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="movies" /></a>

<form action='/search.php' method='GET'>
<input id='searchbar' type='text' size='65' name='search' placeholder="search for movies & tv shows">
<input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' >
</form>

</div>


</div>
```

and here is the full css for it :)

```
<style>
   #topnav{
    background-color: #999;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px;
}
    #nav{
        margin-left: 10px;

        }

   </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper div to the form and float it right

```
<div id="topnav"> 


<div id="nav">
<a href="../index"><img src="/img/putlockermedia_logo.png" /></a>

<a href="../Shows"><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Shows" /></a>

<a href="../movies"><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="movies" /></a>

    <div id="right">
<form action='/search.php' method='GET'>
<input id='searchbar' type='text' size='65' name='search' placeholder="search for movies & tv shows">
<input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' >
</form>
    </div>

</div>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 <style>
 #topnav{
    background-color: #999;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#nav{
   margin-left: 10px;
}
#right {
    float:right
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to use the `float:left; width:50%;` for form inside the `div`

check the [fiddle link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rCf7T/) sample